# Match the path but ignore query parameters when specifying userscript target

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a script I want to run on my test website on all pages with `mydomain.com/test.html` and anything further into that, such as pages with extra GET query like `mydomain.com/test.html?a=1&b=2`.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: `http://example.com/test.html*`

Comment: That doesn't help at all. I've currently got it set to 'mydomain.com/test.html' in the greasemonkey options, but as soon as the domain goes to 'mydomain.com/test.html?a=1&b=2' it no longer runs the script

Edit: I should say, i've got the correct url, with http:// and whatnot, the problem arises from the extra parts after the url

Comment: Literally just 'http:// mydomain/test.html' and same in matched. Space so it doesn't just link

Comment: I downvote this question because it doesn't provide sufficient info to resolve or at least address the problem. Please edit the info into the post. Specifically: full URL (can be made up, but must follow original pattern), specific code you used in `@include` command.

Comment: Well, seeing as you've just resolved it, and the fact that I have put the full URL above, I'd say you were wrong about it providing insufficient evidence to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use regular expressions for specifying userscript targets. For example:

```
@include    /https?:(www\.)?\/\/example\.com\/index\.html\?x=y/
```

This will match:

- Both `http` and `https`, because `?` after `s` character means it's not required
- both `www` and non `www` variant (`?` again, this time used for group `(www\.)`)
- only `/index.html?x=y` path. Even the GET query parameters will affect the script

If you want to match any GET query, just replace `x=y` with `.*?` which in Regular expressions means *anything*:

```
@include    /https?:(www\.)?\/\/example\.com\/index\.html\?.*?/
```